# How to search a MongoDB document using multiple select drop-down list filtering combinations?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following sample data within a collection called `inventory`:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc1", description: "product 1", status: "Low" }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "abc2", description: "product 2", status: "Medium" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz1", description: "product 3", status: "High" }
```

I also have a screen that contains three select drop-down lists filters that are used to query the above inventory on, i.e.:

```
Item
Description
Status
```

Here the user can elect to filter data on all three drop-downs to obtain required report data output or can just select on Item alone, to filter report data on.

My question is, how can I perform the required `mongodb.find` query based on selected values from drop-downs that could be just one selection or even just on two?

For example, if the user selects the following combination and presses the submit button, I expect to only see this document:

```
Item = "abc2" selected by user
Description = no selection
Status = no selection
```

Code:

```
db.inventory.find(
  {
    "item" : "abc2",
    "description" : "",
    "status" : ""
  }
);
```

Since I am not sure what filter selections will be performed, I need to cater for all combination types.

Choosing just the `item` returns me 0 documents as it's expecting values for both `description` and `status` but it should actually return me the one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it would be better to build this condition in your application logic but you can consider building MongoDB query using [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) and [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) like below:

```
var query = {
    "item" : "abc2",
    "description" : "",
    "status" : ""
}

db.col.find({
    $expr: {
        $and: [
            { $cond: [ { $eq: [ query.item, "" ] }, true, { $eq: [ "$item", query.item ] } ] },
            { $cond: [ { $eq: [ query.description, "" ] }, true, { $eq: [ "$description", query.description ] } ] },
            { $cond: [ { $eq: [ query.status, "" ] }, true, { $eq: [ "$status", query.status ] } ] },
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Do both the $expr and $cond operators need to be used with an aggregate?

Comment: @tonyf `$expr` allows you to run aggregation expressions in `find()` and `$cond` is one of them so you need both